# Will the angular velocity of a particle decrease when it slides off the turntable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

Assume a particle with a fixed mass is put on a rotating turntable. When the turntable is fast enough, the particle will slide off. So, will the angular velocity of the particle decrease at the instant that it slides off the turntable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the particle were moving at an angular velocity equal to the turntable's angular velocity, then it wouldn't slip in the first place. And having a higher angular velocity than the turntable is not possible. This is because just before slipping, the friction was at its maximum value. Now if the angular velocity of the particle would be more than it was before, then the friction would not be able to make up for the increased centripetal force 
($m\omega^2 r$, and here $r$ is increasing) due to increased angular velocity and radius.

Comment: Why having a higher angular velocity than the turntable is not possible, is it due to things related to energy?

Comment: @DiamondPhysics I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Can the angular velocity stay the same as the increased angular velocity of the rotating turntable?

Comment: @DiamondPhysics But you yourself have asked about the angular velocity *when* the particle slips/slides...

Comment: But by F=mw^2r, increased angular velocity will cause the radius to decrease for limited kinetic friction when it slides off?

Comment: @DiamondPhysics No! The body doesn't always have to be in equilibrium. When $\omega$ increases, the centrifugal force (in the rotating frame) increases. The centrifugal force pushes the body outwards and once it overcomes friction, the body experiences a net force in the outwards direction, increasing its radius.

Comment: I will move this discussion to chat, can you help me with the basics of circular motion? I am kind of confused...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107617/discussion-between-fakemod-and-diamond-physics).